# Project Euler Prob#2 Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is my very first post here and yes as you can probably tell I'm starting to learn how to code. I'm trying to solve prob #2 of Euler Project but keep getting the following error for line 5:

```
undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass(NoMethodError)
```

I googled the error and apparently it mans that whatever I'm trying to apply the method to doesn't recognize it. This is my code

```
def FiboV1()
    fibo_list=[1,2]
    for i in fibo_list
        if i>=2 then
            y=fibo_list[i]+fibo_list[i-1]
            fibo_list.push(y)
        end
    end
    print fibo_list
end
```

I don't understand why '+' comes up as an undefined method here, could you please help?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What's the objective of the problem?

Comment: The code attempts to access `fibo_list[2]`, which is `nil`.

Comment: small suggestion, whenever you are tying to use arrays, try using `.each` method. Like `fibo_list.each do |f| puts f end`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is than array indexes start to count from `0`(not 1). When you enter the `if` block for the first time you call `fibo_list[i]` with an `i = 2`, but the element does not exist.

That line should should work if you just change it to:

```
y = fibo_list[i-1] + fibo_list[i-2]
```

I did not check for other problems, because you did not explain what your code should do.